# O(n) complexity algorithm to remove instances of value from unsorted list without remove() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework question to write a function which is part of a class bagOfWords to remove instances of a value from an unsorted list.  The list operations we can use don't include remove().  We need to have only O(n) complexity and the naive algorithm doesn't perform that well.

I tried a naive algorithm.  This is too complex an algorithm.  It uses list.pop(index) which of itself has O(n) complexity and it has two loops.  Since we are not allowed to use list.remove() and because a list comprehension would have the same complexity but in a more succinct syntax, I'm trying to find a better implementation.

I thought maybe the solution was a quicksort algorithm because I might be able to do this with O(n) complexity if I first sort the list.  But how would I then remove this item without the complexity of pop(index)?  Now I'm wondering if searching for the pattern via a KMP algorithm would be the solution, or hashing.

```
 def remove(self, item):
        """Remove all copies of item from the bag. 
        Do nothing if the item doesn't occur in the bag.
        """
        index = 0
        while index < len(self.items):
            if self.items[index] == item:
                self.items.pop(index)
            else:
                index += 1
```

The complexity is quadratic.  However, I want a complexity that is O(n)

Edit: to clarify, we are actually constrained to modifying an existing list.

Comment: Can you use `del self.items[x]` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon that will still have the same problem of `.pop` and `.remove`, i.e., it will be O(N^2) overall to remove the elements from the list.

Comment: You can't sort in O(n), and it would be cheating not to count the sort.

Comment: Hang on, I just noticed: "because a list comprehension would have the same complexity" - this is not true, you can write an O(n) list comprehension as @juanpa has commented below. It copies the list, but if that's acceptable it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** The simplest (and arguably just "correct") way to do this is to use a list comprehension:

```
self.items = [x for x in self.items if x != item]
```

It's O(n), and it's faster than the below options. It's also by far the most "pythonic".

---

However, it does create a new copy of the list. If you are actually constrained to modifying an existing list, here's my original answer:

> Here's an "in-place" O(n) algorithm that uses two pointers to collapse the list down, removing the unwanted elements:
>
> ```
> ixDst = 0
> for ixSrc in range(0, len(items)):
>   if items[ixSrc] != item:
>     items[ixDst] = items[ixSrc]
>     ixDst += 1
> del items[ixDst:]
> ```
>
> (See it run [here](https://repl.it/repls/ShadyDecimalTags))
>
> The only questionable part is resizing the list down with `del`. I believe that's in-place and "should" be O(1), since the slice we're removing is at the end of the list.

Also, a more pythonic in-place answer (and a bit faster) was suggested by @chepner in the comments:

```
self.items[:] = (x for x in self.items if x != item)
```

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga and @chepner for the discussion.

Comment: You would do it because OP said "in-place" was required. I agree that it's not the best way, but it is possible, and would not be slower than the list comprehension.

Comment: Well, the time complexity would be the same, but certainly the list-comprehension will be faster due to constant factors. In any event, I don't think it is clear that the operation has to be in-place. OP should clarify. IOW, it isn't clear if the operation has to be in-place only for the *bag object*, which utilizes a `list` to store the items. In which case, modifying the list-in-place or creating a new-list and re-assigning it would be "in place"

Comment: Maybe, but I'd want to see benchmarks on that (if for some reason performance was particularly important).

Comment: Oh, if that was the case, then yes, just make a new list.

Comment: Well, your for-loop version will perform more closely, but I would use `for ix_src, element in enumerate(items)` to get better performance. Manually indexing in Python is slow. Each indexing operation involves a special-method resolution (faster than regular method resolution, to be fair), then the corresponding function call all at the interpreter level. In contrast, iterating directly over the list pushes all of that down into the C layer. Still, `items[ixDst] = items[ixSrc]` operation will slow things down if there are a lot of elements to filter.

Comment: Interesting, I bow to your superior knowledge of python internals.

Comment: I claim that `self.items[:] = (x for x in self.items if x == item)` is also in-place, with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

Comment: A quick and dirty benchmark: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/d7cdf5e72fbe2db80ef342aa7d7437af apologies if you don't have pandas/matplotlib, it's just convenient to visualize

Comment: @chepner it is.

Comment: @chepner That's clever! (it should be `!=` btw)

Comment: @chepner although, not surprisingly, it is *slower* than simply creating a new list, at least, up until the scale of a million elements, At a certain point, thrashing will kill the new-list approach. The the gist I linked to, I've updated to include the generator approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I wasn't sure if sinking the iteration into the C level would make up for the generator expression.

Comment: Thanks for a great reply and really interesting discussion.  We are actually constrained to modifying an existing list.  Thanks for giving both examples: a constrained example and the more Pythonic one.  I learned a lot!

Comment: `del items[ixDst:]` isn't O(1) if you include refcount management.

Comment: Also the genexp in `self.items[:] = (x for x in self.items if x != item)` is just going to be [materialized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/listobject.c#L606) with [PySequence_Fast](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast) anyway, so it doesn't save any space (or time). List slice assignment wants to know how many elements there are going to be before it starts copying anything.

Answer (score 0):

If elements of you list are relatively small integers or can be represented as such you can make sorting in O(max(maxValue, n)).

The other way is to have pointers to previous and next elements for every element in the list. With that you can delete one element in O(1). However, this makes the operation of getting an item by index run in O(n) time.

Also if the order of items does not matter you can store pairs like `(item, count)` where `count` is number of times `item` appears, then you need to delete only one such a pair for given `item` and have desired complexity.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is all well and good in a language like C where you might actually create a doubly-linked list by hand to do this, but you would never do this in Python, where almost certainly you would stick with the `list` data type, and you would simply just create a new list. Note, Python *doesn't have pointers*. The idiomatic, O(N) solution is `self.items = [x for x in self.items if x == item]`

Comment: Well yeah, I agree that it is the best way in practice, pythonic and fast to code, I would use it myself. In my answer I just tried to show some algorithmic methods, classical ones) Besides, seems like it should be `self.items = [x for x in self.items if x != item]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to perform an in-place deletion, you could shift the items over the ones that are deleted and truncate the list in one operation at the end :

```
index = 0
for value in self.items:
    if value != item : 
        self.items[index] = value
        index += 1
del self.items[index:]
```

If you can afford to create a new list (without a list comprehension), you could do it like this:

```
cleanedItems = []
for value in items:
    if value != item: cleanedItems.append(value)
self.items = cleanedItems
```

Comment: Iterating in reverse avoids index management problems, but it doesn't avoid quadratic worst-case time complexity. It just makes the worst case a bit different. For example, if the entire first half of the list needs to be deleted and none of the second half needs to be deleted, you hit quadratic runtime.

Comment: You are right, I adapted the approach in my answer to perform all the in-place deletion in one operation.