# Multiply every third element of a list by two

Tags: python, list, collections, iteration, list-comprehension

Input data: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` 
Output data: `[1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 12, 7, 8, 18, 10]`

I have read many answers where were suggested to use slice notation with including first element. But in my case I should take each 3rd element of the list.

Is it possible to improve my realization?

```py
for index in range(len(data)):
    if (index + 1) % 3 == 0:
        data[index] = data[index] * 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - multiply every other element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452170/python-multiply-every-other-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do it with slice notation:

```
data[2::3] = [x*2 for x in data[2::3]]
```

The `data[2::3]` means every 3rd element starting at element index 2 (i.e. the third element). You can reassign back to a slice as well, allowing for this very succinct syntax.

Comment: You can improve this by doing `data[2::3] = (x*2 for x in data[2::3])`.  This uses a generator, and avoids the creation of a temporary list.

Comment: @TomKarzes But `data[2::3]` itself is a temporary list. To truly avoid the creation of a temporary list one should use `data[2::3] = (x * 2 for x in itertools.islice(data, 2, None, 3))`.

Comment: @blhsing Oh, good point.  I was only looking at the "outer" temporary list.  I guess you could also do `data[2::3] = (data[i]*2 for i in range(2, len(data), 3))`

Comment: Actually, [list slice assignment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/listobject.c#L606) will [materialize](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast) the generator to a list anyway, as I learned from the final comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464566/369)

Answer (score 3):

There is a "step" parameter on the `range` iterator:

```
for index in range(2, len(data), 3):
    data[index] *= 2
```

Would that do?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution isn't too bad.  It can be improved by simply iterating over the desired indices directly, rather than iterating over all indices and skipping the ones you don't want:

```
for index in range(2, len(data), 3):
    data[index] *= 2
```

This produces the desired result:

```
[1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 12, 7, 8, 18, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use cycle from itertools and zip to pair items with their multipliers:

```
data   = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

from itertools import cycle
result = [n*m for n,m in zip(data,cycle([1,1,2]))]

# [1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 12, 7, 8, 18, 10]
```

OR, you can use enumerate()

```
result = [ n*max(1,i%3) for i,n in enumerate(data) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could organize it a little bit by passing a third argument to the range() function, like this:

`for index in range(2, len(data), 3):
        data[index] = data[index]*2`

Answer (score 1):

... and the winner is:

```
Calculation time in seconds and results validation test.
1.150 question_by_akrapovich
0.331 answer_by_Tom_Karzes_and_Prune
0.333 answer_2_by_Manuel_Montoya
0.373 answer_by_Blorgbeard
0.816 answer_1_by_Alain_T
2.850 answer_2_by_Alain_T
```

Combined code for time testing and results validation:

```
import time


def question_by_akrapovich(data):
    for index in range(len(data)):
        if (index + 1) % 3 == 0:
            data[index] = data[index] * 2
    return data


def answer_by_Tom_Karzes_and_Prune(data):
    for index in range(2, len(data), 3):
        data[index] *= 2
    return data


def answer_by_Blorgbeard(data):
    data[2::3] = [x*2 for x in data[2::3]]
    return data


def answer_1_by_Alain_T(data):
    from itertools import cycle
    return [n * m for n, m in zip(data, cycle([1, 1, 2]))]


def answer_2_by_Alain_T(data):
    return [ n*max(1,i%3) for i,n in enumerate(data) ]


def answer_2_by_Manuel_Montoya(data):
    for index in range(2, len(data), 3):
        data[index] = data[index]*2
    return  data

def test(f):
    n = 10_000_000
    data = [i + 1 for i in range(n)]
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    data = f(data)
    run_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    if n != len(data):
        print('error in list length', n, len(data))
        exit(1)
    for i in range(n):
        j = i + 1
        m = j * 2 if j % 3 == 0 else j
        if data[i] != m:
            print('error in data', i, m, data[i])
            exit(1)
    print('%.3f %s' % (run_time, f.__name__))


print('Calculation time in seconds and results validation test.')
for f in [question_by_akrapovich, answer_by_Tom_Karzes_and_Prune,
          answer_2_by_Manuel_Montoya, answer_by_Blorgbeard,
          answer_1_by_Alain_T, answer_2_by_Alain_T]:
    test(f)
```